# WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel

Tags: amd-gpu

i am new to all linux and i am trying to install amd graphics drivers, it gives me this error, can someone help me?

```
mawo@DESKTOP-4L5PH5G:~/Downloads$ amdgpu-install -y --usecase=graphics
INFO: i386 architecture has not been enabled with dpkg.
Installation of 32-bit run time has been excluded.
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:2 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/6.0.2 jammy InRelease
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 110 kB in 3s (41.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
amdgpu-dkms is already the newest version (1:6.3.6.60002-1718217.22.04).
amdgpu-lib is already the newest version (1:6.0.60002-1718217.22.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
```

idk how to fix this i am new

Comment: Sadly this appears to be a hardware issue and not related to programming so its the wrong place to post this question.  I would look on their website to find support, but its times like these people realize the true cost of a free operating system.